# Anyone found a way to move the insert marker one character to the left of to the right?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s

The new **insert marker in Android 2-2**, you get when pressing a text field in edit more, and which gives you the ability to move it to the point where you want to start editing, **is all very nice**. Compared to the previous way of long pressing the men key to shop up the cursor keypad, it's quicker and gives you more options.

**But has anyone found a way to move this marker one character to the left or to the right** (apart from the obvious of course, which is holding it and moving it to the left or to the right).

I found that positioning the marker to the exact place is hard. 90% of the times you put it just one character to the left or to the right. If you than want to move it again, it's very hard to move it just one character, especially when that character is s small one ( a space, an i or an l).

Comment: Uh, isn't that new marker part of Android 2.3?

Comment: @Al Everett: Don't know, at least it's on my Samsung Galaxy S now that I have upgraded from 2.1 two weeks ago.

Comment: Might be specific to the Galaxy S.

Comment: The Galaxy S phones don't have a track ball or optical track pad, do they?  That's normally how it would be done.

Comment: I just drag it one to left or right, it's pretty accurate and doesn't seem to go too far by accident at all. MBraedley's right, Galaxy S's don't have the trackball/pad, this is a Samsung TouchWiz addition that came with Froyo and massively improves text selection and cursor control. I find it easier than using the trackball was on my old HTC Magic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Swype, slide your finger from the Swype button (bottom left) to the SYM key. This will display a set of navigation buttons - including a dpad that lets you move the text input.

[image]

Comment: Yep, the answer is basically "Yes, if your keyboard has arrow keys".  The Android keyboard really should.

Comment: The asker didn't mention anything about using Swype, which is still in closed beta. This isn't really a useful answer.

Comment: Swype is installed from the factory on the SGS line, and the tags implied he had that device.

Comment: Ah. My mistake. Withdrawn, then.

Comment: The awesomeness of Swype continues to amaze me.

Comment: I really don't like SWYPE. Maybe I should try it out more, but I want to press keys - even soft keys is preferable to the SWYPE method. But that's just me , of course.